# How to compare the values in the form against the validations in the model

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have set up a model with validation rules and want to compare them to the information being put into the form. As of now i have the values being declared and they validate

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.ReviewsContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
    xtype: 'reviewscontainer',


    config: {

        title: 'Reviews',
        iconCls: 'compose',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'reviews'

            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                align: 'right',
                ui: 'confirm',
                text: 'Leave Review',
                docked: 'bottom',
                centered: 'true',

                handler: function () {
                    if (!this.overlay) {
                        this.overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
                            xtype: 'formpanel',
                            requires: ['FirstApp.model.ReviewCheck'],
                            id: 'reviewed',
                            modal: true,
                            hideOnMaskTap: true,
                            showAnimation: {
                                type: 'popIn',
                                duration: 250,
                                easing: 'ease-out'
                            },
                            hideAnimation: {
                                type: 'popOut',
                                duration: 250,
                                easing: 'ease-out'
                            },
                            centered: true,
                            width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? 260 : 400,
                            height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? 220 : 400,
                            styleHtmlContent: true,

                            items: [{
                                    docked: 'top',
                                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                                    title: 'Leave Review'
                                },

                                {
                                    xtype: 'fieldset',

                                    title: 'Reviews',
                                    items: [{
                                            xtype: 'textfield',
                                            name: 'name',
                                            label: 'Name',
                                            placeHolder: 'name',
                                            id: 'text'
                                        }, {
                                            xtype: 'textfield',
                                            name: 'business',
                                            label: 'Place'
                                        }, {
                                            xtype: 'textfield',
                                            name: 'rating',
                                            label: 'Rating'
                                        }, {
                                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                                            name: 'review',
                                            label: 'Review'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    items: [{
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            text: 'Submit',
                                            ui: 'confirm',
                                            handler: function () {

                                                console.log("Hello");
                                                //var values = Ext.getCmp('reviewed').getValues();

                                                // var text= Ext.getCmp('text').getValue();

                                                //   var value = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#text')[0].getValue();


                                                //var reviewCheckForm = this.getReviewCheck();
                                                //var currentForm = reviewCheckForm.getRecord();
                                                // var newValues = reviewed.getValues();

                                                // currentForm.set("name", newValues.name);
                                                // currentForm.set("business", newValues.business);
                                                // currentForm.set("review", newValues.review);


                                                var form = formPanel.getForm(); //Get the basicform instance
                                                var record = form.getRecord(); //Get your record loaded in the form
                                                form.updateRecord(record); //Update your record with the current form values
                                                var errors = record.validate(); //Validate your record



                                                // console.log(newValues);
                                                // var data = Ext.create('FirstApp.model.ReviewCheck', {
                                                //         name: 'dfhd',
                                                //     business: 'sdfs',
                                                //     id: 1,
                                                //   review: 'sfsd'
                                                //  });

                                                //   var errors = data.validate();


                                                // var errors = currentForm.validate();
                                                console.log('Number of errors: ' + errors.getCount());




                                                if (!errors.isValid()) {
                                                    console.log('Number of errors: ' + errors.getCount());

                                                    errors.each(function (item, index, length) {
                                                        // Each item in the errors collection is an instance of the Ext.data.Error   class.
                                                        console.log('Field "' + item.getField() + '" ' + item.getMessage());
                                                    });
                                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Form is invalid!');
                                                } else {

                                                    var values = Ext.getCmp('reviewed').getValues();
                                                    // prints the values filled in the form 
                                                    // text fields of name, email and message.     
                                                    console.log(values.name + "," + values.place + "," + values.rating);


                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                        url: 'http://insert.php',
                                                        params: values,
                                                        success: function (response) {
                                                            var text = response.responseText;
                                                            Ext.getCmp('reviewed').reset();
                                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', "Review successfully created.", Ext.getCmp('reviewed').hide(), Ext.StoreMgr.get('Reviews').load());
                                                            console.log("Im Here");
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            scrollable: false
                        });
                    }

                    this.overlay.show();
                }
            }

        ]
    }
})



Ext.define('FirstApp.model.ReviewCheck', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'business',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'review',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ], // fields
        validations: [{
                field: 'name',
                type: 'presence',
                error: 'Name must be present',
                message: 'Name is required.'
            }, {
                field: 'business',
                type: 'presence',
                message: 'Place is required.'
            }, {
                field: 'review',
                type: 'presence',
                message: 'Review is required.'

            }
        ] // validations
    } // config
}); // define()
```

How do i set name,business,id and review to the values been taking in from the form

Answer (score 0):

First get the instance of your view

```
var reviewCheckForm = this.getReviewCheck();
```

then take the record from it

```
var currentForm = reviewCheckForm.getRecord();
```

then get the new values from the same form

```
var newValues = reviewCheckForm.getValues();
```

Then set the new values to the record and validate it

```
currentForm.set("name", newValues.name);
currentForm.set("business", newValues.business);
currentForm.set("review", newValues.review);
```

then validate it

```
var errors = currentForm.validate();

if (!errors.isValid()) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField("title")[0].getMessage(), Ext.emptyFn);
    currentForm.reject();
    return;
}
```

you can follow [this](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/) simple tutorial to get more understading and for you reference and [here](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/) is the model validation part.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, i have tried both answers and a thousand different things but i think it could be down to my file structure so i have posted all the code in the original question to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [updateRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-updateRecord) function of the [form](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic).
Don't manually set all your properties as @Mayur showed in his example.

Something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Submit',
    ui: 'confirm',
    handler: function () {
        var formPanel = this.up('formpanel'); //Get the formpanel
        var form = formPanel.getForm(); //Get the basicform instance
        var record = form.getRecord(); //Get your record loaded in the form
        form.updateRecord(record); //Update your record with the current form values
        var errors = record.validate(); //Validate your record

        console.log('Number of errors: ' + errors.getCount());

        if (!errors.isValid()) {
            console.log('Number of errors: ' + errors.getCount());

            errors.each(function (item, index, length) {
                // Each item in the errors collection is an instance of the Ext.data.Error   class.
                console.log('Field "' + item.getField() + '" ' + item.getMessage());
            });
            Ext.Msg.alert('Form is invalid!');
        } 
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, i have tried both answers and a thousand different things but i think it could be down to my file structure so i have posted all the code in the original question to see if that is the case.

Comment: You can't just use formPanel. I edited my code to navidate to the formPanel with up.

Comment: Also you don't seem to load a record in the form in the first place. With `loadRecord(record)` somewhere

Comment: Hi i have tried the above code but i am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'up' . With regards to loadRecord(record) how do implement this?

Comment: Hmm try `this.up()` instead of `button.up()`. As for the loadRecord, you should have an instance of your record somewhere right? Or do you create a new record?

Comment: Hi i have updated the code and changed formPanel.getValues() and i can now see the values entered. But i am now getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getRecord' I have updated the section of your code above so you can see the where the error is occuring

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue...JSF + Richfaces
basically, i have multiple tabs...something like...(Not exact code)

```
<rich:tab name="a">
  <inputText id="a1" values="">
  <inputText id="a2" values="">
</rich:tab>

<rich:tab name="b">
  <inputText id="b1" values="">
  <inputText id="b2" values="">
</rich:tab>
```

Steps
1) User first will go to tab "a" and change the "a1" value to say "newValue"
2) Without submitting the form.. go to tab "b".
Since, User did not submit the form, User should should get warning message saying .."You have un-saved data in tab a"....

How to implement this?

Thanks.. really appreciate it.